# Isolation high side MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, mosfet-driver, isolation

I have high side [MOSFET component VN7003ALH](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2108051130_STMicroelectronics-VN7003ALHTR_C2150147.pdf), with the following information, it has an input pin instead of a gate.
[image]

As the electrical specification shows, the MOSFET drain and source voltage adjust by the input level, my question is how can I isolate VCC & GND pin from the input signal?
My first PCB test board shows if microcontroller GND and MOSFET GND are not connected, it does not work, I can use an optocoupler for the input pin, but how to solve the GND pin of the MOSFET driver.
Any help really appreciated
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a MOSFET with an integrated gate driver. This makes it easier to use: otherwise you'd need a separate gate driver.

Whatever isolation solution you think you may need, you'd need it whether the MOSFET was stand-alone or with an integrated gate driver. So the question is hardly related to the part you're using, although it changes the character of isolation you want: if you had a discrete MOSFET, perhaps you'd want an isolated gate driver as a single part. Here, the gate driver is integrated with the mosfet, so you only need to use a digital isolator that otherwise matches the requirements of the INPUT pin.

Why do you not want to connect GND and INPUT both to the microcontroller circuitry? That's how they are meant to be used - if you don't need galvanic isolation. But not connecting GND doesn't change things: the INPUT signal is not isolated either, so if you think that *only* connecting INPUT is somehow "better" or "safer": that's not the case. Just connect the GND terminal as you did before, and you're done.

Since this is a high-side driver, the VCC pin is really the high side power supply rail, *not* microcontroller's VCC. The OUT pin is the switched power rail. The GND is the reference for the control inputs/outputs, and is not directly related to the output potentials. GND has to be within a certain range below VCC: too close to VCC, and there's not enough voltage to run the part. Too low, and the maximum voltage rating is exceeded.

Comment: @kuba-hasnt-forgotten-monica yes it's correct, the MOSFET GND is the reference for the control inputs/outputs but the problem is I should connect the Battery GND to MOSFET GND which is common with MCU GND, all part should be in the same GND plane which is blowup my MCU isolation, that's why I intend the Isolate the MOSFET GND & input pin from MCU GND